# Parameter encoding in gfortran module files

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Let's say I have a module:

```
module testParam

    real, parameter :: x=1.0, xx=10.0
    real, parameter :: pi=3.14

end module testParam
```

Compile it with

```
gfortran -c testParam.f90
```

And look in the generated module file

```
cp testparam.mod testparam.gz
gunzip testparam.gz
```

The trimmed output is:

```
(2 'pi' 'testparam' '' 1 ((PARAMETER UNKNOWN-INTENT UNKNOWN-PROC UNKNOWN
IMPLICIT-SAVE 0 0) () (REAL 4 0 0 0 REAL ()) 0 0 () (CONSTANT (REAL 4 0
0 0 REAL ()) 0 '0.323d70c@1') () 0 () () 0 0)

4 'x' 'testparam' '' 1 ((PARAMETER UNKNOWN-INTENT UNKNOWN-PROC UNKNOWN
IMPLICIT-SAVE 0 0) () (REAL 4 0 0 0 REAL ()) 0 0 () (CONSTANT (REAL 4 0
0 0 REAL ()) 0 '0.1000000@1') () 0 () () 0 0)

5 'xx' 'testparam' '' 1 ((PARAMETER UNKNOWN-INTENT UNKNOWN-PROC UNKNOWN
IMPLICIT-SAVE 0 0) () (REAL 4 0 0 0 REAL ()) 0 0 () (CONSTANT (REAL 4 0
0 0 REAL ()) 0 '0.a000000@1') () 0 () () 0 0)
```

Then we can see that the value of x has been stored as '0.1000000@1' and pi has been stored as '0.323d70c@1' and xx as '0.a000000@1'. How can i convert the string encoded parameter back into a number?

Given the value of the x term i originally assumed it was simply, for a format a@b, a*10^b but the value for pi is hex encoded (and for the xx variable int(0xa)==10.0 so at least part of it is hex). Maybe its some sort of hex encoded floating point number?

Comment: Which version of gfortran?  Although to be honest, the way I'd do it is probably `use testParam; print*,x;end` etc.

Comment: 5.3.1, i would as well but i'm writing some code that pareses the mod file to work out what the module is doing without "running" it.

Comment: It looks to me like a form of dumping the binary form of a single-precision floating point value with the bits somewhat decomposed.  The part between the "0." and the "@" is clearly the mantissa.  I might guess that the "@1" represents the exponent in some form or fashion, but it would be more clear with numbers that would have a non-zero exponent.

Comment: 5065465484.03264654 maps to 0.12decde@9 so it does look like the right of the @ is the exponent

Comment: You could read the relevant parts of the gfortran source code.

Comment: It seems that we can check the number by typing 0x3.23d70cP0 (in the REPL of Julia, if you have it installed), which gives 3.140000104904175. As for bigger numbers, if you use real(8), parameter :: A =1234567890.12345d0 etc in the module file, we can convert the hex output similarly to the original one (after moving the decimal point according to @*).

Comment: Ah, i never realized hexs could have an exponent (P+something) on the end which is why none of my attempted at converting the hex ever gave the right number

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @roygvib comment this works for python

```
def hextofloat(s):
    # Given a hex like parameter '0.12decde@9' returns 5065465344.0
    man, exp =s.split('@')
    exp=int(exp)
    decimal = man.index('.')
    man = man[decimal+1:]
    man = man.ljust(exp,'0')
    man = man[:exp]+'.'+man[exp:]
    man = man +'P0'
    return float.fromhex(man)
```

Split the string value into the mantisa (0.12decde) and exponent (9), get the hex number to the right of the decimal place (12decde) and pad it with enough zeros (12decde00) so its at least as long as the exponent, put the decimal place back in (12decde00.0) then put a 'P0' (12decde00.P0) on the end and pass to float.fromhex()

Comment: Depending on how general it needs to be, you would also want to test with Inf, NaN, and possibly +/- 0 and denormals (the last two are probably OK as-is).